# How can I get the value of DocumentID in the Message field?

Tags: sql, sybase

How can I get the value (DocumentID) in the Message field

```
example:
ID                        Message
7898    <Portfolio><DocumentID>10545</DocumentID></Portfolio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  ID,
document_id = xmlextract("//Portfolio/DocumentID/text()", Message)
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ASE version older than 12.5.1 you can accomplish this using character manipulation functions:

```
select 
  id, 
  substring(
    message, 
    charindex('ID>', message)+3,
    charindex('</Doc', message) - charindex('ID>', message)-3
    ) as DocumentID
from your_table
```

If you're on a later version using xmlextract as suggested in the answer by RADAR seems much easier.